# change format of a column in a element of a list with lapply

Tags: r

I have a list of data.frames and I want to change the class of one column of the data.frame (from factor to date). I was trying to use lapply but then, the original list only contains that column (not the whole data.frame). I don't understand this behaviour..to solve this I use a common loop, but I was wondering if anyone could have any suggestion. 
Let's say, as an example, I have this simple data:

```
       m1 <- data.frame("date"=c("2010-02-03","2010-01-05"),"value"=c(5,3))
       m2 <- data.frame("date"=c("2010-02-03","2010-01-05"),"value"=c(1,3))
       mylist <- list(m1,m2)
       #change date 
       newlist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) as.Date(x$date))
```

newlist will have only the date..
Is there any way to use lapply for that..I am working with large dataset, and usually lapply works fine, but in this case, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Many thanks.

Comment: `lapply(mylist, transform, date = as.Date(date))`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about transform, perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `transform`

```
lapply(mylist, transform, date = as.Date(date))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function you have to first change the `date` column and then return `x`

```
newlist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) {
    x$date <- as.Date(x$date)
    x
})
newlist
# [[1]]
#         date value
# 1 2010-02-03     5
# 2 2010-01-05     3
# 
# [[2]]
#         date value
# 1 2010-02-03     1
# 2 2010-01-05     3
```